# Error While Execute the script using JavaCode

Tags: java, scripting, nsis

Hi i use the following java code and a sample NSIS script while i run this code i got an error.

My JavaCode:

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class SampleClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    Process p;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            r.exec("makensis.exe myscript.nsi");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and my NSIS script is

```
    OutFile "Your ComputerName.exe"
Name "Your ComputerName"
Caption "ComputerName"
XPStyle "on"

Function .onInit
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName" "ComputerName"
  StrCmp $0 "" win9x
  StrCpy $1 $0 4 3
  MessageBox MB_OK "Your ComputerName : $0" 
  Goto done
win9x:
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName" "ComputerName"
  StrCpy $1 $0 4 3
  MessageBox MB_OK "Your ComputerName : $0" 
done:
  Quit ; placed here so we quit the installer; we dont need the other pages for this example.
FunctionEnd

Section "-boo"
;
SectionEnd

; rest of script
```

while i'm executing i got the following error,

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "makensis.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at SampleClass.main(SampleClass.java:14)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Why it happens how to resolve this error?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the java code from the same directory as the makensis.exe file? If not then you will need to use an absolute path

Comment: hi scobal, is it correct r.exec("C:/Users/FSSD/workspace/Snake/makensis.exe sample.nsi"); i also tried this but its not working

Comment: Do you get the same exception when using an absolute path?